# How to prevent that a PHP session variable is modified after unserialize()

Tags: php, oop, session, serialization

I have saved an PHP object (of the class `login`) into the session variable `$_SESSION["login"]`. The class `login` has the methods `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()`.
And before I save the object into the session, I apply the serialize method on it.

On another page I use this session variable. If I execute `unserialize($_SESSION["login"])` the first time I have no problem. But if I use the same command a second time, the result changes.

```
    var_dump($_SESSION["login"]); // everything is how expected and how I saved it
    $temp = $_SESSION["login"]; // here I try to copy the content of the session variable
    $un_ser = unserialize($temp); // I use unserialize to get the original object
    var_dump($_SESSION["login"]); // Problem: not the same as before! Why has it changed?
```

The problem is that I want to read the `login`-object with `unserialize($_SESSION["login"])` for more than only one time but currently it seems to me that it is not possible because the session variable changes after `unserialize(...)`.

To be concrete the string, which I save into the session, is originally:

```
O:24:"BSHelper\login":2:{s:12:"*logged_in";b:1;s:9:"*lehrer";O:22:"BSCore\lehrer":7:{s:12:"*id_lehrer";s:1:"1";s:13:"*geschlecht";s:4:"Herr";s:11:"*nachname";s:10:"testsurname";s:17:"*unterrichtsart";s:6:"Praxis";s:21:"*unterrichtsartKurz";s:1:"P";s:11:"*farbcode";s:7:"#F0BB86";s:8:"*email";s:26:"test@mail.com";}}
```

but after `unserialize(...)` the session variable changed to this

```
O:24:"BSHelper\login":2:{s:12:"*logged_in";b:0;s:9:"*lehrer";N;}
```

I think that it really makes sense to be able to access a whole object out of the session variable because that makes it possible to access values and especially methods of the object.

Comment: what is the value of `$_SESSION["login"]` at the first time?

Comment: Secondly, why are you storing an object to the session..

Comment: Regarding your questions, I have edited my post above.